# How to use extractvalue in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I am trying to convert my Oracle query to SQL Server. The query shown below is causing some difficulty when trying to convert `EXTRACTVALUE`, `XMLSEQUENCE`, `XMLTYPE` functions.

Can anyone help me learn how to convert these to SQL Server?

```
  EXTRACTVALUE(COLUMN_VALUE, 'pipeline/@name') NAME
       FROM TABLE (SELECT XMLSEQUENCE(XMLTYPE(MESSAGE).EXTRACT('processEngine'))
      FROM NMS_MESSAGES WHERE OBJECT_CODE='pe_monitor' AND    ID=@WHERE:PARAM:USER_DEF:INTEGER:PARAM_PROCESS_ENGINE@)) INSTANCENAME
    ,(SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(COLUMN_VALUE, 'processEngine/@id') FROM TABLE (SELECT XMLSEQUENCE(XMLTYPE(MESSAGE).EXTRACT('processEngine'))
      FROM NMS_MESSAGES WHERE OBJECT_CODE='pe_monitor' )) ENGINE_ID
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Think about [XQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189075.aspx). As I See that `EXTRACTVALUE` seems like `@xml.values('(@node/@attr)[1]','type')` and `EXTRACT` is `@xml.nodes('path/path/path')`

If know structure of xml that you ought to parse exactly than you will convert this query without any problems.